# script is reading only last line of an input file

Tags: perl, scripting

Value in my input file (list_muni_nav.txt). Each line is a path for a file, here 'test' and 'test2' are the filename.

```
/iwmnt/default/main/Content/Munic/WORKAREA/work/templatedata/muni_site/security/data/test
/iwmnt/default/main/Content/Munic/WORKAREA/work/templatedata/muni_site/security/data/test2
```

My perl script(as below) should read each line in input file and execute them. But, except last line rest of the lines are not being located by the script. Please see the result

```
    my $content_list = '/home/p12/scripts/list_muni_nav.txt';

print "\t*****************START***************************\n";
print "\tOpening file $content_list\n";
if (open FILE,"$content_list") {
        my $line = <FILE>;
        chomp($line);
        while ($line ne "") {
                print "\t Applying EAs to file $line\n";

                my $setEAVersion= "$getAttrib -s TeamSite/Assocation/Version=1 \"$line\"";
                                 `$setEAVersion`;
                my $setEADCRType= "$getAttrib -s TeamSite/Templating/DCR/Type=muni_site/nav \"$line\"";
                                 `$setEADCRType`;
                my $setEAFormValid= "$getAttrib -s iw_form_valid=true \"$line\"";
                                 `$setEAFormValid`;

                print "\t EAs applied successfully to $line\n";
                print "\t**********************************************************\n";

                $line = <FILE>;
                chomp($line);
        }
```

RESULT:

```
        *****************START***************************
        Opening file /home/pbiswa01/scripts/list_muni_security.txt
         Applying EAs to file /iwmnt/default/main/Content/Munic/WORKAREA/work/templatedata/muni_site/security/data/test
ERROR:02005: Error locating /iwmnt/default/main/Content/Munic/WORKAREA/work/templatedata/muni_site/security/data/test
ERROR:02005: Error locating /iwmnt/default/main/Content/Munic/WORKAREA/work/templatedata/muni_site/security/data/test
ERROR:02005: Error locating /iwmnt/default/main/Content/Munic/WORKAREA/work/templatedata/muni_site/security/data/test
         EAs applied successfully to /iwmnt/default/main/Content/Munic/WORKAREA/work/templatedata/muni_site/security/data/test
        **********************************************************
         Applying EAs to file /iwmnt/default/main/Content/Munic/WORKAREA/work/templatedata/muni_site/security/data/test2
         EAs applied successfully to /iwmnt/default/main/Content/Munic/WORKAREA/work/templatedata/muni_site/security/data/test2
        **********************************************************
```

Please help. Thank you!!

Comment: You output seems to show that the loop has run twice, once for each line. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hello Tom, script ran twice because there are two lines in input file. Each line is path of a file, here 'test' and 'test2' are the filename.

Comment: OK, so the problem is not with the loop itself. What happens if you reverse the order of the lines in the input file? Obvious question, have you checked to make sure that the file `test` definitely exists?

Comment: Yes, test and test2 both the files exist at same location. I changed the order in input file using VI editor and found Locating error for both 'test' and 'test2'. When I changed the order('test' is in last line) in Windows NotePad and upload the input file in Linux box using WinSCP, location error appears for 'test2' only.

Comment: Sounds like wrong newlines.  You are getting an extra character after editing on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that @stark is right, your problem is with newline characters. [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) will remove any trailing string corresponding to the special variable `$/`, which is different on Windows and Linux. You can get round this problem using a regex instead:

```
my $content_list = '/home/p12/scripts/list_muni_nav.txt';

print "\t*****************START***************************\n";
print "\tOpening file $content_list\n";
if (open my $fh, "<", "$content_list") {
    while (my $line = <$fh>) {
        $line =~ s/\s+$//;
        print "\t Applying EAs to file $line\n";

        my $setEAVersion= "$getAttrib -s TeamSite/Assocation/Version=1 \"$line\"";
        `$setEAVersion`;
        my $setEADCRType= "$getAttrib -s TeamSite/Templating/DCR/Type=muni_site/nav \"$line\"";
        `$setEADCRType`;
        my $setEAFormValid= "$getAttrib -s iw_form_valid=true \"$line\"";
        `$setEAFormValid`;

        print "\t EAs applied successfully to $line\n";
        print "\t**********************************************************\n";
    }
```

The `s/\s+$//` regex removes all whitespace characters from the end of the line.

As a bonus, I changed your `open` so that it uses the three argument version and I also changed your `while` loop to avoid code repetition.

Comment: @user3235274 No problem, glad you got it sorted.